# Dynamically allocated string in dynamic structure array(seg fault)

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to read the entire file(line by line)into a char pointer"name" in the struct array.(Wanna keep the names (can be of arbitrary length) in a dynamically allocated string Then I will divide the readed string(name) into chunks(age name score) in struct.I get seg fault.(file format is:

```
age name score
25,Rameiro Rodriguez,3
30,Anatoliy Stephanos,0
19,Vahan: Bohuslav,4.2

struct try{
  double age;
  char *name;
  double score;
};
void allocate_struct_array(struct try **parr,int total_line);
int main(){
int count=0,i=0; 
char ch;
fileptr = fopen("book.txt", "r");
//total line in the file is calculated
struct try *parr;
allocate_struct_array(&parr,count_lines);

//i got segmentation fault at below.(parsing code is not writed yet just trying to read the file)
    while((ch=fgetc(fileptr))!=EOF) {
        count++;
        if(ch=='\n'){
          parr->name=malloc(sizeof(char*)*count+1);
          parr[i].name[count+1]='\0';
          parr+=1;
          count=0;
        }
    }
    fclose(fileptr);
}
void allocate_struct_array(struct try **parr,int total_line){
    *parr = malloc(total_line * sizeof(struct try));
}
```

Comment: Looks like a memory leak: `parr->name=malloc(sizeof(char*)*count+1);`  Should you use `realloc`?

Comment: @Fiddling Bits ,normally yes,but i need do it without realloc on this particular task

Comment: `parr->name=malloc(sizeof(char*)*count+1);` over allocates by a factor of 4 (on x86) and by a factor of 8 (on x86_64) and overwrites the same `parr->name` every time. You want to allocate characters not pointers and you want to allocate for `parr[i].name` not `parr->name`. Simply `parr[i].name = malloc (count + 1);` would suffice. You need to ***validate*** every allocation by ***checking the return***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, in `allocate_struct_array(struct try **parr,int total_line)`, you allocate a block of `struct try` not a block of pointers (e.g. `struct try*`). Your allocation `parr->name=malloc(sizeof(char*)*count+1);` attempts to allocate `count + 1` **pointers**. Moreover, on each iteration, you overwrite the address held by `parr->name` creating a memory leak because the pointer to the prior allocation is lost and cannot be freed.

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

A better approach to your problem is to read each line into a simply character array (of sufficient size to hold each line). You can then separate `age`, `name` and `score` and determine the number of characters in `name` so you can properly allocate for `parr[i].name` and then you can copy the name after you have allocated. If you are careful about it, you can simply locate both `','` in the buffer, allocate for `parr[i].name` and then use `sscanf()` with a proper format-string to separate, convert and copy all values to your struct `parr[i]` in a single call.

Since you have given no way to determine how `//total line in the file is calculated`, we will just presume a number large enough to accommodate your example file for purposes of discussion. Finding that number is left to you.

To read each line into an array, simply declare a buffer (character array) large enough to hold each line (take your longest expected line and multiply by 2 or 4, or if on a typical PC, just use a buffer of `1024` or `2048` bytes that will accommodate all but the obscure file with lines longer than that. (Rule: *Don't Skimp On Buffer Size!!*) You can do that with, e.g.

```
#define COUNTLINES   10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC       1024
#define NUMSZ        64
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* temporary array to hold each line */
    ...
```

When reading until `'\n'` or `EOF` in a loop, it is easier to loop continually and check for `EOF` within the loop. That way the final line is handled as a normal part of your read loop and you don't need a special final code block to handle the last line, e.g.

```
    while (nparr < count_lines) {       /* protect your allocation bounds */
        int ch = fgetc (fileptr);       /* ch must be type int */
        
        if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {  /* if not \n and not EOF */
            ...
        }
        else if (count) {               /* only process buf if chars present */
            ...
        }
        
        if (ch == EOF) {                            /* if EOF, now break */
            break;
        }
    }
```

(**note:** for your example we have continued to read with the `fgetc()` you used, but in normal practice you would simply use `fgets()` to fill the character array with the line)

To find the first and last `','` in the array, you can simply `#include <string.h>` and use `strchar()` to find the first and `strrchr()` to find the last. Using a pointer and end-pointer set to the first and last `','` the number of characters in name becomes `ep - p - 1;`. You can find the `','`s and find the length of name with:

```
            char *p = buf, *ep;         /* pointer & end-pointer */
            ...
            /* locate 1st ',' with p and last ',' with ep */
            if ((p = strchr (buf, ',')) && (ep = strrchr (buf, ',')) && 
                p != ep) {  /* confirm pointers don't point to same ',' */
                size_t len = ep - p - 1;            /* get length of name */
```

Once you have found the first `','` and second `','` and determined the number of characters in `name`, you allocate *characters*, not *pointers*, e.g. with `len` characters in `name` and `nparr` as the struct index (instead of your `i`) you would do:

```
                parr[nparr].name = malloc (len + 1);        /* allocate */
                if (!parr[nparr].name) {                    /* validate */
                    perror ("malloc-parr[nparr].name");
                    break;
                }
```

(**note:** you `break` instead of `exit` on allocation error as all prior structs allocated for and filled will still contain valid data that you can use)

Now you can craft a `sscanf()` format string and separate `age`, `name` and `score` in a single call, e.g.

```
                /* separate buf & convert into age, name, score -- validate */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d,%[^,],%lf", &parr[nparr].age, 
                            parr[nparr].name, &parr[nparr].score) != 3) {
                    fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
                    ...
                }
```

Putting it altogether into a short program to read and separate your exmaple file, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COUNTLINES   10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC       1024
#define NUMSZ        64

typedef struct {            /* typedef for convenient use as type */
  int age;                  /* age is generally an integer, not double */
  char *name;
  double score;
} try;

/* always provde a meaningful return when function can
 * succeed or fail. Return result of malloc.
 */
try *allocate_struct_array (try **parr, int total_line)
{
    return *parr = malloc (total_line * sizeof **parr);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* temporary array to hold each line */
    int count = 0, 
        nparr = 0, 
        count_lines = COUNTLINES;
    try *parr = NULL;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (book.txt by default) */
    FILE *fileptr = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "book.txt", "r");
    
    if (!fileptr) {     /* always validate file open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-fileptr");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fileptr)) {  /* read/discard header line */
        fputs ("file-empty\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* validate every allocation */
    if (allocate_struct_array (&parr, count_lines) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-parr");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (nparr < count_lines) {       /* protect your allocation bounds */
        int ch = fgetc (fileptr);       /* ch must be type int */
        
        if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {  /* if not \n and not EOF */
            buf[count++] = ch;          /* add char to buf */
            if (count + 1 == MAXC) {    /* validate buf not full */
                fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
                count = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (count) {               /* only process buf if chars present */
            char *p = buf, *ep;         /* pointer & end-pointer */
            
            buf[count] = 0;             /* nul-terminate buf */
            
            /* locate 1st ',' with p and last ',' with ep */
            if ((p = strchr (buf, ',')) && (ep = strrchr (buf, ',')) && 
                p != ep) {  /* confirm pointers don't point to same ',' */
                size_t len = ep - p - 1;            /* get length of name */
                
                parr[nparr].name = malloc (len + 1);        /* allocate */
                if (!parr[nparr].name) {                    /* validate */
                    perror ("malloc-parr[nparr].name");
                    break;
                }
                
                /* separate buf & convert into age, name, score -- validate */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d,%[^,],%lf", &parr[nparr].age, 
                            parr[nparr].name, &parr[nparr].score) != 3) {
                    fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
                    if (ch == EOF)                  /* if at EOF on failure */
                        break;                      /* break read loop */
                    else {
                        count = 0;                  /* otherwise reset count */
                        continue;                   /* start read of next line */
                    }
                }
            }
            nparr += 1;                             /* increment array index */
            count=0;                                /* reset count zero */
        }
        
        if (ch == EOF) {                            /* if EOF, now break */
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fileptr);                    /* close file */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nparr; i++) {
        printf ("%3d   %-20s %5.1lf\n", 
                parr[i].age, parr[i].name, parr[i].score);
        free (parr[i].name);            /* free strings when done */
    }
    free (parr);                        /* free struxts */
}
```

(**note:** Never Hardcode Filenames or use Magic-Numbers in your code. If you need a constant, `#define ...` one. Pass the filename to read as the first argument to your program or take the filename as input. You shouldn't have to recompile your code just to read from a different filename)

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `dat/parr_name.txt`, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/parr_name dat/parr_name.txt
 25   Rameiro Rodriguez      3.0
 30   Anatoliy Stephanos     0.0
 19   Vahan: Bohuslav        4.2
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/parr_name dat/parr_name.txt
==17385== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17385== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17385== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17385== Command: ./bin/parr_name dat/parr_name.txt
==17385==
 25   Rameiro Rodriguez      3.0
 30   Anatoliy Stephanos     0.0
 19   Vahan: Bohuslav        4.2
==17385==
==17385== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17385==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17385==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 5,965 bytes allocated
==17385==
==17385== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17385==
==17385== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17385== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**Using `fgets()` To Read Each Line And A Temp Array For `name`**

To not leave you with the wrong impression, this problem can be simplified substantially by reading each line into a character array using `fgets()` and separating the needed values with `sscanf()`, saving `name` into a temporary array of sufficient size. Now all that is needed is to allocate for `parr[nparr].name` and then copy the temporary `name` to `parr[nparr].name`.

By doing it this way you substantially reduce the complexity of reading character-by-character and by using a temporary array for `name`, you eliminate having to locate the `','` in order to obtain the length of the name.

The only changes needed are to add a new constant for the temporary name array and then you can replace the entire read-loop with:

```
#define NAMSZ       256
...
    /* protect memory bounds, read each line into buf */
    while (nparr < count_lines && fgets (buf, MAXC, fileptr)) {
        char name[NAMSZ];       /* temporary array for name */
        size_t len;             /* length of name */
        
        /* separate buf into age, temp name, score & validate */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d,%[^,],%lf", &parr[nparr].age, name,
                    &parr[nparr].score) != 3) {
            fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        len = strlen (name);    /* get length of name */
        
        parr[nparr].name = malloc (len + 1);        /* allocate for name  */
        if (!parr[nparr].name) {                    /* validate allocation */
            perror ("malloc-parr[nparr].name");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (parr[nparr].name, name, len + 1);
        
        nparr += 1;
    }
    fclose(fileptr);                    /* close file */
    ...
```

(same output and same memory check)

Also note you can allocate and copy as a single operation if your compiler provides `strdup()`. That would reduce the allocation and copy of `name` to a single call, e.g.

```
        parr[nparr].name = strdup (name);
```

Since `strdup()` allocates memory (and can fail), you must validate the allocation just as you would if you were using `malloc()` amd `memcpy()`. But, understand, `strdup()` is not standard C. It is a POSIX function that isn't part of the standard library.

The other improvement you can make is adding logic to call `realloc()` when your block of struct (`parr`) is full. That way you can start with some reasonably anticipated number of struct and then reallocate more whenever you run out. This will eliminate the artificial limit on the number of lines you can store -- and remove the need to know `count_lines`. (there are numerous examples on this site of how to use `realloc()`, the implementation is left to you.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations, I am grateful. It will be very useful in my learning process.I am working on it now.

Comment: Good, glad to help. Take it slow, there is a lot there. If you get stuck, just drop a comment below and I'm happy to help further (through it will be after I get a good night sleep `:)`